# Weighted sum of arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

I was pondering this problem (not a homework):

[image: problem]

What are the coefficients {a_i} that cancel all powers except the biggest one ?

The values for n=1,2,3 are easy to find, Wolfram-alpha helped find the next ones.

Is there a formula to generate them?

Comment: These are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n\brace k} x^{\underline{k}} =
\sum_{k=1}^n {n\brace k} \frac{x!}{(x-k)!} = x^n.$$

with the Stirling numbers of the second kind.

To see this combinatorially write it as

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {x\choose k} {n\brace k} k! = x^n.$$

Let $x$ be the number of elements of some set. Then $x^n$ counts the
number of $n$-tuples with components chosen from this set. This is the
RHS. The LHS  classifies the tuples according to the number of different
values that  appear, say there are $k$ of these. Then we must first
choose these values which  gives ${x\choose k}.$ Next we partition the
$n$ slots into $k$  non-empty disjoint subsets where the slots in a
subset all hold the same value  from the $k$ that we have chosen. We can
assign the latter to the subsets  in $k!$ different ways. This gives the
factor ${n\brace k}\times k!$ and  hence the LHS. (We have shown that it
holds  for positive integers $x.$ With both sides being polynomials in
$x$ it  holds for all $x$ where we define ${x\choose k} =
x^{\underline{k}}/k!.$)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the Stirling numbers. And your combinatorial interpretation is very insightful.

Comment: Good to know it helped.